# Get to know device screen size programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Please have a look at related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345909/how-to-use-recyclerview-according-to-device-screensize). I got to know some hint from comments and now putting it in a new way.

I am using a `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridView` adapter to display the data. How do I get to know that how many items needed to be loaded for current devices to fit the whole screen?

## process

- Determine the screen size
- Determine how many items needed to be loaded to fit full screen
- Fetch data from Server with number of items
- Display them
- When user scroll down device fetch same amount of items and so on.

## Question

I am not able to understand How to get done with first two points.

## Code for Adapter

```
public class StaggeredGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredGridAdapter.StaggeredGridView> {

private Context context;
private String INTENT_VALUE = "warehouse";
private List<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<Warehouse>();
private AppDelegate app;
int size;

public StaggeredGridAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    app = (AppDelegate) context;
}

public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response) {
    size = response.size();
    warehouses = response;
}

@Override
public StaggeredGridView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    StaggeredGridView staggeredGridView = new StaggeredGridView(layoutView);
    return staggeredGridView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StaggeredGridView holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(warehouses.get(position).getFace());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return size;
}

class StaggeredGridView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView textView;

    public StaggeredGridView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WareHouseDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_VALUE, warehouses.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

## code for filling data into adapter

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.staggering_grid);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
mAdapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(mContext);
mAdapter.addItems(response);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Are you mainly concerned with knowing when to load more items from the server?

Comment: Have a look at this [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) that is your first port of call in determining the size of the screen.

Comment: @ElliotM Not actually because it's is the first activity. I just want to know How many items do I need to fetch from server because every request is only returning 10 items

Comment: @t0mm13b Got it but is there any way to determine the number of items ?

Comment: @Def You know how the data be rendered in the adapter, ie. height/width for one item, then it's a matter of dividing the client height of the view by the height of the rendered item?

Comment: I am using `wrap_content`

Comment: @t0mm13b So finally I am loading maximum amount of items i.e. 50. can you please how to set it up "Load more " option for the device who cannot accept 50 items in one screen? Let's say I xhdpi device can only show 20 items. So can I make coordinate between them to load next 20 item from the list which is already fetched

Comment: By the sounds of it, you need to dynamically post a request, instead of just 10, post 20 for hdpi, for xhdpi, post 30, for xxhdpi post 40 if you get the gist.

Comment: @t0mm13b That means there is no way to figure it out dynamically this equation  `Show data in device as per screen device / out of 50 Items ` ?

Answer (score 1):

As to find the Height and Width, you can use the `DisplayMetrics`.

```
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

This `displayMetrics` will give Height, Width and Density. Use the height of the single `View` (or row) and the total height to calculate the number of items.

Why do you want the `Exact` number of items, if it's a server call you are making, you could just make a rough estimate on the number of items based on the device size. Also, I think it's better to keep `the number of items sent by server` a constant and not dependent on the device height. If you received more than the number of items you can fit in the screen, well, the user can scroll to see them anyways.

Comment: Great! But how can I determine the no of items needed to be fetched from `displaymetrics`

Comment: Using your way, the width is exact, but height is not exactly the device screen height. Because it doesn't take status bar's height into account.

Comment: Yes, I prefer using `DisplayMetrics` for the `density`. Using that and the `height` of the root layout we could get the height in terms of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to work out how much you'll need to load, you could set it up to automatically load more when you're close to the end of the list.

Consider this method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StaggeredGridView holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(warehouses.get(position).getFace());
}
```

This is called when the item is ready to be displayed on the screen. By doing something like `if(position > getItemCount() - 5{ // load more }` then you could be automatically loading more as and when they're required.

Comment: The problem is one request to server is returning 10 items only.